# Calling a function on captured group in re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> base64_encode = lambda url : url.encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
>>> s = '<A HREF="http://www.google.com" ID="test">blah</A>'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=href=")([\w:/.]+)(?=")', base64_encode(r'\1'), s, flags=re.I)
<A HREF="XDE=" ID="test">blah</A>
```

The base64 encoding of the string `http://www.google.com` is `aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29t` not `XDE=`, which is the encoding of `\1`.

How do I pass the captured group into the function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You pass a function to `re.sub` and then you pull the group from there:

```
def base64_encode(match):
    """
    This function takes a re 'match object' and performs
    The appropriate substitutions
    """

    group = match.group(1)
    ... #Code to encode as base 64
    return result

re.sub(...,base64_encode,s,flags=re.I)
```

Comment: Ha ha you Pythoners are too fast. Was writing this answer :) +1

Comment: What if my function has more than one parameter?

Comment: @aberger -- re will pass a single parameter (the match) to the callback.  If you want to pass a second argument that is only dependent on the match (or is constant), you can wrap the first callable with a `lambda` or a simple function defined on the previous line:  `re.sub(..., lambda m: callback(m, 'another_arg'), s, flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 4):

Write your function to take a single parameter, which will be a match object (see http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#match-objects for details on these). Inside your function, use `m.group(1)` to get the first group from your match object `m`.

And when you pass the function to re.sub, don't use parentheses:

```
re.sub("some regex", my_match_function, s, flags=re.I)
```