# What's the best alternative function of Lua string.gsub in Python?

Tags: python, lua, gsub

What's the best alternative function of **Lua**'s global pattern substitution function `string.gsub(s, pattern, function)` in **Python**? e.g.

```
> string.gsub("banana", "(a)(n)", function(a,b) return b..a end) -- reverse any "an"s
bnanaa  2
```

**UPDATE**: I'd like to implement a complex function during pattern substitution in Python like Lua's `string.gsub`, which can be implemented by Python's `re.sub` with [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17136150/7630831) or [lambda expr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18737927/7630831).

Comment: `re.sub` is the function you want.

Comment: `re.sub`, maybe? `re.sub('(a)(n)', r'\2\1', 'banana')` What do you mean by *"best"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe : I'd like to implement a complex function during pattern substitution in Python like Lua's `string.gsub`, which can also be implemented by Python's `re.sub` with [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17136150/7630831) or [lambda expr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18737927/7630831).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`string.gsub(s, pattern, replace [, n])`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) returns a pair of values, *the modified string and the number of substitutions made*, in Python, you need to use [`re.subn`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.subn):

> **`re.subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`**
>   Perform the same operation as `sub()`, but return a tuple (`new_string, number_of_subs_made`).

See a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/mq6QEH):

```
import re
print (re.subn("(a)(n)", r"\2\1", "banana"))
# => ('bnanaa', 2)
```

And you also may use an anonymous method (or a lambda expression for simpler scenarios) as a replacement argument:

```
print (re.subn("(a)(n)", lambda m: "{}{}".format(m.group(2), m.group(1)), "banana"))
# => ('bnanaa', 2)
```

See [another Python demo](http://ideone.com/eFp8Jn).

**NOTE**: If you need no number of replacements made, use a mere [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).